# Using Material-UI for Reactjs without Node.js/NPM

Tags: reactjs

Is there a minified material-ui version for react available somewhere?

I'm planning to include the jsx files externally in html, so was wondering is there any static/cdn resource available, apart from installing it via node/npm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is `<link href="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.9/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />`. More info here: https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/react/introduction

Comment: Isn't this a completely different library?

Answer (score 4):

## Using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) without NPM

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <!-- React -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <!-- Babel -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- MUI -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { Button } = MaterialUI; // Components are available in MaterialUI object
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
         Hello World!
      </Button>, 
      document.getElementById("root") 
    );
  </script>
</body>
```

Reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn